# Select generic interface type from string parameter

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to call a generic function by passing a dynamically-selected handler. The handler's parameter has a `type` field matching a user-provided type string. I'm not sure how to express that in TypeScript. How can I adjust my types such that `problemFunction` correctly sets the generic type when calling `getAndUseFoo`?

```
interface Foo {
  type: string;
}
interface FooA {
  type: 'A';
}
interface FooB {
  type: 'B';
}

const handlers = {
  A: (fooA: FooA) => console.log(fooA),
  B: (fooB: FooB) => console.log(fooB),
}

// Untyped library function that we know returns some Foo-extending type
function fooFactory(type: string): any {
  return type === 'A' ? {type: 'A'} : {type: 'B'};
}

// Retrieves a Foo and calls a handler against it before doing other work
function getAndUseFoo<T extends Foo>(type: string, handler: (foo: T) => any) {
  const foo: T = fooFactory(type);
  handler(foo);
  // Do more work with foo
}

function problemFunction(type: 'A' | 'B') {
  // TypeScript thinks handlers[type] is a union type with incompatible types
  const foo = getAndUseFoo(type, handlers[type]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a good answer to this.  You can either duplicate code to walk the compiler through the different cases:

```
function problemFunction(type: 'A' | 'B') {
  const foo = (type === 'A') ? 
    getAndUseFoo(type, handlers[type]) : 
    getAndUseFoo(type, handlers[type]) ; // déjà vu
}
```

or use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) which is not type safe:

```
function problemFunction(type: 'A' | 'B') {
  const foo = getAndUseFoo(type, handlers[type] as (foo:Foo)=>void); // danger
}
```

I've [asked for a way to handle this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051) which would tell the compiler to distribute its control flow analysis over values of union types, but unless lots of people clamor for it (e.g., go to that issue and give it a  and comment about their use case) I doubt it will be seriously considered.  Frankly, a type assertion is easy, and specifically meant for times when you know more than the compiler.  So that would be my suggestion.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: You could declare overloads so that, although code will as you say be somewhat duplicated, no pointless logic will be executed at runtime.

Comment: I don't see how overloads would remove the error... could you elaborate?

Comment: I meant `function getFoo(type: 'A'): FooA; function getFoo(type: 'B'): FooB;` but there is actually another way. `function getAndUseFoo<T extends keyof typeof handlers>(type: K, handler: typeof handlers[K])`

Comment: Looks good, but if I try that it pushes the union-of-functions problem up into the implementation of `getAndUseFoo` where `handler(foo)` is not recognized as safe. And additionally, that lets you call `getAndUseFoo(type, handlers.B)` without a warning, which isn't safe... you only want to support "matching" pairs of `type` and `handler`.  Please feel free to post an answer with your solution if you think it's better than or an alternative to what I put in above; as it stands I can't really see how those suggestions improve things, but that could be a limitation of Stack Overflow comment boxes.